# Problem with Rest Webservice Code coverage

Tags: rest-api, webservices, rest, apex-webservice

I have the following set of lines in my code

```
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    AreaRequestWrapper areaRequestRecord = (AreaRequestWrapper)System.JSON.deserialize(requestString, AreaRequestWrapper.class);
            if(areaRequestRecord.OpportunityId == null || areaRequestRecord.OpportunityId == '')
            {
                res.statusCode = 401; 
                res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(res.statusCode+' : Mandatory field OpportunityId was not sent in the Request JSON');
            }
```

My issue is that, when I am writing the test class for the above code, the the code is covered till line

res.statusCode = 401;

But the responseBody line does not get covered.

Answer (score 0):

I think that here you can use a HTTP Mock Factory to handle different status codes.

**Let's say we have this call out:**

```
public class ExternalSearch {
  public class ExternalSearchException extends Exception{}

  public static String googleIt(String query) {
   Http h = new Http();
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com?q='+query);
   req.setMethod('GET');
   HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

     if(res.getStatusCode() != 200){
            throw new ExternalSearchException(
        'Did not received a 200 status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
     }

      return res.getBody();
  }

}
```

**You can use this mock factory:**

```
@isTest
public class HTTPMockFactory implements HttpCalloutMock {
    protected Integer code;
    protected String status;
    protected String body;
    protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders;

    public HTTPMockFactory(Integer code, String status, String body, Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
      this.code = code;
      this.status = status;
      this.body = body;
      this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
}
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
      HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
      for (String key : this.responseHeaders.keySet()) {
        res.setHeader(key, this.responseHeaders.get(key));
      }
      res.setBody(this.body);
      res.setStatusCode(this.code);
      res.setStatus(this.status);
      return res;
    }
}
```

**Then the test class can test your status codes using the mock class:**

```
@isTest
private class ExternalSearch_Tests {

    @isTest static void test_method_one() {
      HttpMockFactory mock = new HttpMockFactory(200, 'OK', 'I found it!', new Map<String,String>());
      Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
      String result;

      Test.startTest();
      result = ExternalSearch.googleIt('epic search');
      Test.stopTest();
      system.assertEquals('I found it!', result); 

    }

      @isTest static void test_method_two() {

      HttpMockFactory mock = new HttpMockFactory(500, 'Internal Server Error', 'Error 500', new Map<String,String>());
      Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
      String result;
      Boolean caught = false;  

      Test.startTest();
            try {
                  result = ExternalSearch.googleIt('epic search');

            } catch (ExternalSearch.ExternalSearchException e) {
                  System.assertEquals('Did not received a 200 status code: 500', e.getMessage(), 'caught the right exception');
                  caught = true;
                  }
                    System.assert(caught, 'threw expected exception');
           Test.stopTest();  
           system.assertEquals(null , result); 
    }
 }
```

You can check more details [here](http://ccloudonline.nl/?page_id=1767&preview_id=1767&preview_nonce=3551842850&preview=true).